# How to rename media file before transfer from channel A to B (client.send_message)?

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I'm looking to a way to rename file before it's transfer to the other channel

so what I want is:

- telethon is reading texts and media(with caption) from channel "A"
- then rename media to specific name "abc.jpg" or "abc.mp3"
- telethon send texts and media(with caption) to channel "B"

i'm using this code

```py
@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=input_channels_entities))
async def handler(event):
    for output_channel in output_channel_entities:
        await client.send_message(output_channel, event.message)
```

is there specific to do? I looked over Telethon docs and searched every place but no luck

Answer (score 0):

In your case you didn't find it on Telethon docs out because is not related to Telegram, but to the file itself.

Since you're willing to rename the file **before** sending it to the other channel, the simplest way is to **download the file itself** via its file ID stored in the Telegram servers thanks to the **[getFile](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getfile)** method.

Once you download it locally, you can rename it directly and let your chatbot send it once through the **methods offered by Telegram Chatbot API**.

This last point is generic, because it depends by the **file type** you're willing to forward (audio, image, video, zip, document, etc.): additional information could be find out here: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#available-methods